# Saving an image inserted by user in a folder under WEB-INF in a jsp project

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

I am trying to save an image inserted by an `<input>` field in a form by the user to a folder named imgs under the `WEB-INF` folder and store in the table column of the product the path of that photo so i can later display them in a products page for my online shop.
I don't know how to send the image to the java file (using jdbc server) so i can save it and also how i can save it. I have researched online but I have not fount what i am looking for. Below is my `.jsp` file.

```
<body>
     <%
        if(request.getParameter("btn") != null){
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String description = request.getParameter("description");
            double price = Double.valueOf( request.getParameter("price"));
            String brand = request.getParameter("brand");
            String type = request.getParameter("type");
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("quantity"));
            File picture = 
                    
            Client client = Client.create();
            WebResource webResource =client.resource("...link.../"+name+"/"+description+"/"+price+"/"+brand+"/"+type+"/"+quantity+"/"+picture);
            ClientResponse myresponse = webResource.accept("text/plain").get(ClientResponse.class);
        }
    %>
     <div class="p-5" >
        <h1 id="title" class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="font-size:4rem;">Edit your Profile</h1>
        <form class="container " method="post">
            
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                    <label for="name">Product name:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name"><br>
                </div >
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                    <label for="description">Description:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea><br>
                </div >
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-3">
                    <label for="price">Price:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price"><br>
                </div >
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                    <label for="brand">Product brand:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="brand"><br>
                </div >
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                    <label for="type">Product type(running, walking, casual ,etc...):</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="type"><br>
                </div >
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                    <label for="quantity">Available quantity:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="quantity"><br>
                </div >
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-6">
                    <label for="picture">Product picture:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="picture"><br>
                </div >
            </div>
            <button   type="submit" name="btn">Sign in</button>
     </form>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't write files under WEB-INF, use a directory outside the tree of the web app.

Comment: And you will need to explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: you should upload the image to the server using another servlet or java class, and then store the image's name in the database. There's a lot of examples for doing this. Also, it's a better practice to validate when the form is subtmitted by using: if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")){ than validating it using a parameter like the way you are doing it

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have seen some examples using java.image.io of how i can save the image from the java class with a few tries i believe i can make it work but the main issue is how i can pass it through to the java class from the jsp page because i have not found anything online for passing a file the way i pass the string and number variables in the code above.